# How to push() data from 2 json feeds into a single array

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

As per title, I have 2 json feeds which I am trying to use. The first details which departure airports fly to which destination airports, the second i'd like to use to look up the friendly names of the airports which are flown to. I have a set of information pages. I'd like to output a list of destinations flown to on each page dynamically from these two feeds. I'm unclear as how to push() these into an array and sort, etc. Any help very much appreciated.

**First feed**

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/routesRouteInformation.action',
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (response) {
  jsonRoutes = response;
  }
});
```

example file:

```
{
"LGW":[
 {"arvAirportCode":"EDI","multiSector":"M","endDate":"26-Oct-2013 00:00:00"},
 {"arvAirportCode":"NCL","multiSector":"D","endDate":"26-Oct-2013 00:00:00"},
 {"arvAirportCode":"SYY","multiSector":"M","endDate":"26-Oct-2013 00:00:00"},
 ...Etc
```

**Second feed**

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/airportsRouteInformation.action',
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (response) {
  jsonInfo = response;
  }
});
```

example file:

```
[{"airportCode":"LGW","airportCountry":"UK","airportName":"London Gatwick", "longitude":"53.910297","latitude":"-8.818492"},
"airportCode":"BLL","airportCountry":"DK","airportName":"Billund","longitude":"55.740322","latitude":"9.151778"},
{"airportCode":"RNN","airportCountry":"DK","airportName":"Bornholm"},    {"airportCode":"BCN","airportCountry":"ES","airportName":"Barcelona","longitude":"41.2969","latitude":"2.07833"}
...Etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.extend(object1, object2);
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the quick response, I'll take a look at this. How would I ensure that the objects coincide with one another i.e. LGW from jsonRoutes assigns to London Gatwick from jsonInfo ?

Comment: The reason for the second object is purely to get the friendly name which corresponds to the airport code. LGW = London Gatwick. I think I need to do a look up on the second file, match LGW and its airportName but i'm really unsure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Given your data I would retrieve first the airport info and then for each airport info lookup in the routes and add them to it. 
Something along :

```
$.each(infos, function(index, info){
info.routes = routes[info.airportCode];
});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for this - can you write the code as you would expect it to be given the above. I think I follow your logic, i'm just a little unsure of how to interpret it :-)